# How to download data into Rstudio via "Rblpapi"?

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

Good afternoon. Recently I've experienced a problem with downloading data from Bloomberg information system into RStudio via "Rblpapi" package. In order to get this package on my PC I executed the following commands:
`install.packages("Rblpapi")`
`library(Rblpapi)`

This code was proceeded succesfully. Further, in order to establish the connection between my PC and Blooberg I did the following:
`blpConnect()`

Then I received the error message:

**25MAR2021_12:27:10.598 4484:7384 ERROR blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:671 blpapi.session.transporttcp.{4}.localhost:8194 Connection failed**

**25MAR2021_12:27:10.598 4484:7384 WARN blpapi_platformcontroller.cpp:371 blpapi.session.platformcontroller.{4} Platform: 0 failed 1 consecutive connect attempts, stopped trying to reconnect.**

**Error in blpConnect_Impl(host, port, appName) :Failed to start session.**

Therefore, I couldn`t establish the connection between my PC and Bloomberg.

Could you, please, tell me, how this problem can be solved?

Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Hi, I think you have additional software to download as you can read here : https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/issues/193

Comment: Are you running a Bloomberg terminal on the same PC?

Comment: @assylias Yes, I am.

Comment: Is bbcomm.exe running?